# when using stcmd co with -vl flag file is being checkout even at the second time the command is being executed

Tags: checkout, starteam

Actually I have 2 different questions regarding the stcmd co with -vl flag:

1) when using stcmd co without -vl flag, the file is being checked out only at the first time. If I run it again the file is being skipped. BUT when adding the -vl flag to the stcmd co command, the file is being checked out at each and every run. How can I avoid it? (I tried to run -f NCO but then when using different label the file was not checked out as well.)
2) I had 1 file with 2 revisions, after I checked out the file by label of the first revision using stcmd co and then tried to run stcmd co without any label specified in order to get latest version, I got message that the file is modified therefor it hasn't been checkout. Since I want to get only the changed files I want to avoid the -force option. Any other way to force the file to be checked out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Three things needs to be changed:

1. Checkout by *Config-label*, not by View-Label - use `-cfgl LABELNAME` instead of `-vl LABELNAME`
   this will correctly identify the status of your local files in comparison to the given label.
2. Use a *filter* to check-out only files that needs to be checked-out:
   `-filter MGIOU`
   (this means: All files, except those that are 'Current')
3. Do use *force* (the `-o` flag) to make sure the *filter* works as intended.

To sum it up, the command should look like this:

```
stcmd co -p "user:pwd@host:port/MyProject/MyView/"  ...  -o  -filter MGIOU  -cfgl  "MY_LABEL"  ...
```